# Flutter Web: Docker Unable to Build M1

Tags: flutter, docker

I am deploying a Flutter web app with Docker. When I run the command `flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit --release` on my local terminal, it works. However, when the command is run in the Dockerfile using `docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -t us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/ABCDE-d1935/ABCDE/web-ui .`, it *sometimes* works, and sometimes doesn't. The error message is below, which shows the build failing when flutter tries to build the web files.

```
 > [build-env 13/13] RUN flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit --release:
0.347    Woah! You appear to be trying to run flutter as root.
0.347    We strongly recommend running the flutter tool without superuser privileges.
0.347   /
0.347 
1.105 Downloading Web SDK...                                              3.3s
7.642 
7.858 Compiling lib/main.dart for the Web...                          ../../runtime/bin/file_linux.cc: 486: error: Unexpected EINTR errno
86.89 ../../runtime/bin/file_linux.cc: 486: error: Unexpected EINTR errno
86.89 Aborting reentrant request for stack trace.
86.89 version=3.4.0-167.0.dev (dev) (Thu Feb 22 12:02:16 2024 -0800) on "linux_x64"
86.89 pid=12, thread=153, isolate_group=(nil)((nil)), isolate=(nil)((nil))
86.89 os=linux, arch=x64, comp=no, sim=no
86.89 isolate_instructions=0, vm_instructions=5555575c2560
86.89 fp=7ffff71fe440, sp=7ffff71fe310, pc=5555577c019c
86.90 Aborted
```

When it doesn't work, it tends to not work 3-5 times, or after an hour of waiting, before it works again. This issue has been happening many times over the last month, and pops up randomly. I've only recently started building web apps of flutter, so I am not sure if it's a new issue related to recent Mac updates or another recent change. My machine is Apple M1 Pro - 14.2.1.

**Appendix**

Dockerfile

```
#Stage 1 - Install dependencies and build the app in a build environment
FROM debian:latest AS build-env
# Install flutter dependencies
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl git wget unzip libgconf-2-4 gdb libstdc++6 libglu1-mesa fonts-droid-fallback lib32stdc++6 python3 sed
RUN apt-get clean
# Clone the flutter repo
RUN git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git /usr/local/flutter
# Set flutter path
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/usr/local/flutter/bin:/usr/local/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin"
# Run flutter doctor
RUN flutter doctor -v
# RUN flutter channel master
# RUN flutter upgrade
# Copy files to container and build
RUN mkdir /app/
COPY . /app/
WORKDIR /app/
RUN flutter clean
RUN flutter pub get
RUN flutter pub upgrade
RUN flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit --release
# Stage 2 - Create the run-time image
FROM nginx:1.25.2-alpine
COPY .prod.env .prod.env
ENV WEB_APP_URL="..."
RUN export $(cat .prod.env)
COPY --from=build-env /app/build/web /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

pubspec.yaml

```
name: karmakard
description: Next generation platform for discounts, community engagement, and fundraising. 
publish_to: 'none'

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.6 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  go_router: ^12.0.0
  flutter_bloc: ^8.1.3


  geolocator: ^10.1.0
  firebase_messaging: ^14.7.16
  cloud_firestore: ^4.15.5 
  cloud_functions: ^4.6.5 
  firebase_auth: ^4.17.5 
  firebase_core: ^2.25.4 
  firebase_crashlytics: ^3.4.15 
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^5.4.14 
  firebase_storage: ^11.6.6 
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.6.0
  group_button: ^5.3.3
  easy_sidemenu: ^0.5.0
  dropdown_button2: ^2.3.9
  side_navigation: ^1.0.4
  data_table_2: ^2.5.8
  equatable: ^2.0.5
  intl: ^0.18.1
  freezed_annotation: ^2.4.1
  dartz: ^0.10.1
  freezed: ^2.4.5
  flutter_form_builder: ^9.1.1
  json_annotation: ^4.8.1
  flutter_login: ^4.2.1
  google_sign_in: ^6.1.6
  sign_in_with_apple: ^5.0.0
  device_info_plus: ^9.1.1
  firebase_ui_auth: ^1.10.0
  firebase_ui_oauth_google: 1.2.17
  firebase_ui_oauth_apple: ^1.2.14
  firebase_ui_oauth_facebook: ^1.2.14
  firebase_ui_oauth_twitter: ^1.2.14
  firebase_ui_localizations: ^1.8.0
  http: ^1.1.0
  introduction_screen: ^3.1.12
  awesome_snackbar_content: ^0.1.3
  another_flushbar: ^1.12.30
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.5.0
  const_date_time: ^1.1.0
  flutter_typeahead: ^5.0.1
  form_builder_validators: ^9.1.0
  universal_html: ^2.2.4
  file_picker: ^6.1.1
  flutter_dropzone: ^3.0.6
  dio: ^5.4.0
  webview_flutter: ^4.4.2
  flutter_html_iframe: ^3.0.0-beta.2
  loader_overlay: ^4.0.0
  loading_animation_widget: ^1.2.0+4
  image_cropper: ^5.0.1
  image_picker: ^1.0.7
  dotted_border: ^2.1.0
  image_card: ^0.0.4
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.7.0
  flutter_expandable_table: ^2.0.1
  flutter_otp_text_field: ^1.1.1
  webview_flutter_web: ^0.2.2+4
  flutter_native_timezone: ^2.0.0
  phone_form_field: ^9.0.5
  dots_indicator: ^2.1.2
  permission_handler: ^11.2.0
  geocoding: ^2.1.1
  draggable_bottom_sheet: ^1.0.2
  bloc_concurrency: ^0.2.3
  geoflutterfire_plus: ^0.0.19
  carousel_slider: ^4.2.1
  label_marker: ^1.0.1
  flutter_map_math: ^0.1.7
  maps_launcher: ^2.2.0
  url_launcher: ^6.2.5
  flutter_phone_direct_caller: ^2.1.1
  nfc_manager: ^3.3.0
  card_loading: ^0.3.2
  flutter_animate: ^4.5.0
  animated_text_kit: ^4.2.2
  lottie: ^3.1.0
  url_strategy: ^0.2.0
  flutter_dotenv: ^5.1.0
  pointer_interceptor: ^0.9.3+7

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  build_runner: ^2.4.6
  json_serializable: ^6.7.1

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/styles/
    - .env
  fonts:
    - family: SocialIcons
      fonts:
        - asset: packages/firebase_ui_auth/fonts/SocialIcons.ttf
```